# NetBeans 7.2.1 Cpp Error warning initializing vector

Tags: c++, netbeans

if i initalize a vector like in the picture below, i get this errors from Netbeans but the GCC compailer doesnt show the errors and builds the program successfully.
What might be the reason and a solution?
Thanks[image]

Comment: Maybe the intellisense doesn't have initializer lists and/or in-class member initialization down yet. What does it say when you hover over the icon?

Comment: in says: unable to resovle identifier m_alphabet. unexpected token: {. unexpected token: }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses initializer lists to initialize your `std::vector`. This is a feature introduced with C++ 2011 and not necessarily supported, yet, but all system processing C++. gcc is quite good in implementing new features and the recent version of gcc are fairly complete with respect to the standard. I don't know the status of C++ 2011 support for NetBeans but I would assume it is just not, yet, supported.

Comment: As you can see on picture OP is using g++ under NetBeans. Problem is with version of g++. Moreover it is not mainly initializer list, but initialization of member variable not in ctor ....

Comment: Ok, but what can i do to resolve this problem? how can i init the vector so that it shows no warnings? I also tried to change the project settings by putting c++11 as the compilation standard

Comment: As PiotrNycz pointed out, the use of initializer lists may not be the problem. In this case, you can move the initialization out of the class definition and into the constructors of your class: `SortIt::SortIt(): m_alaphabet({"A", "B", "C" /*...*}) {}` (and likewise for all the other constructors; one way to avoid repeated code is to move this initialization into its own class). If initializer lists are a problem, too, you'll need to build up the vector separately.

Comment: Danke Dietmar, i tried to put the init within the constructor but it goes out of scope (has no elements) in other functions.

Comment: Did you put it into the member initializer list? It shouldn't end up empty in this case. If you put it into the bodybof the constructor I can imagine that you ended up initializing a temporary object (since I don't see the source I can't say what is happening).

Comment: I did, and the funny part is a have a similar class that gets created the same way which works just fine. The code is here if you are willing to take a look. https://github.com/aldialimucaj/sortit/blob/master/Sortit.cpp Thanks in advance

Comment: The constructor not taking a `_rdepth` parameter creates a temporary `SortIt` object. I guess, it is meant to delegate to the other constructor instead. To do you'd need to delegate in the member initializer list. Of course, delegating constructors are also a feature new in C++ 2011...

Comment: GREAT! Thanks i worked with the delegation constructor. I coming from a strong Java background and this stuff just seems so obvious for a programming language. Danke nochmals und alles Gute